# AEM bundle not loading due to unresolved dependency

Tags: aem

After a minor version change in all POM files of the project, core bundle does not start properly due to an unresolved dependency with core components:

`com.adobe.cq.wcm.core.components.models,version=[12.28,13) -- Cannot be resolved`

The bundle remains in state "Installed" even when the "play" button is clicked to start it.

We are using AEM cloud SDK, which is supposed to have the core components integrated.

I've tried cleaning the .m2 maven repository folder, recompile the project with different flags (autoInstallPackage and autoInstallSinglePackage)... but no luck.

Edit:

Compilation is successful and instance starts properly, but an error is shown when visiting any page, even in edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause was the `<aem.sdk.api>` property in the *pom.xml* file. It was set to a version higher than the instance SDK API. Apparently, download a new version of the SDK monthly is the recommended way to keep your local environment in sync with your AEM cloud instances: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-learn/cloud-service/local-development-environment-set-up/aem-runtime.html?lang=en#when-to-update-the-quickstart-jar